# Change route in map on basis of my current location

Tags: android, google-maps, uber-api, direction

I am working on a Application like a cab. Now i have two points, source and destination and i draw a route with those points. Now what i need is if i will navigate on another route then it must draw polyline on another route.

For example A is starting point and B is ending point. Route is drawn from A to B directly. Now I am navigating on that route, suppose in b/w I go to c location and then I will go to B. Then the path on map must be A to C then C to B.

I used Ubercaraniamtion for live tracking, below is reference link.

https://github.com/amanjeetsingh150/UberCarAnimation/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/developers/uberanimation/MapsActivity.java

Comment: Do you mean waypoints? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints

Comment: no excatly not but similar like this

Comment: Similar how? Why not use waypoints to go from point A to C to B?

Comment: Look i am making app like cabs. then i can't use waypoint.